# Sieve: put mail to subaddress into folder

Tags: email, dovecot, sieve

Is it possible to write a Sieve rule like

```
if envelope :detail "to" "$x" {
  fileinto "inbox.$x";
}
```

but for all possible `$x`? I.e. if the user created a folder `inbox.foo` I want mail addressed to `user+foo@domain` to land there automatically. The [spec](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5228) doesn't seem to support this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out that's what the [variables extension](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5229) is for.

```
require "variables";
if envelope :detail :matches "to" "*" {
  fileinto "inbox.${1}";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For me this one worked:

```
require ["variables", "fileinto", "envelope", "subaddress", "mailbox"];

if envelope :matches :detail "to" "*" {
    # you can prefix with INBOX/ or INBOX. if necessary
    # remove :create if you want to permit only existing mailboxes
    fileinto :create "${1}";
}
```

See the example from here:
https://wiki.dovecot.org/Pigeonhole/Sieve/Examples

Obviously this would also be just an option to be turned on:
`lmtp_save_to_detail_mailbox=yes`